# LUbuntu OEM instalation "Prepare for Shipping to End User" missing

Tags: lubuntu, oem

I have done a OEM installation for LUbuntu 15-.10 and I expect to see a script in the desktop named "Prepare for Shipping to End User" but the desktop is empty...

It's a error in the OEM installer for LUbuntu?
There is any way to launch the script by hand? I can't find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was the network connection. Same installation with same ISO in the same computer works OK with the network connected during the installation.

Comment: Wondering if installing and running oem-config-prepare would also resolve the issue.

Comment: Thanks for posting that solution, Carlos. Had the same issue in Zorin OS 16.2 (unlike Ubuntu and Mint, its OEM mode can only be accessed by editing the boot options to "linux /casper/vmlinuz boot=casper maybe-ubiquity quiet splash oem-config/enable=true ---"). Connecting to the network during install restored the "Prepare for shipping to end user" Desktop icon.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to run this script by hand by the command oem-config prepare.   Here is the man page. http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/en/man8/oem-config-prepare.8.html

Although for oem config of lubuntu it will unfortantely use the ubuntu with unity oem slideshow as noted here https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lubuntu-artwork/+bug/1442817